# How To Use Button "OK" In Looping System?

Tags: android, button, spinner

I want to make a button to save/print/show the names in 2 spinners sequently when this process's working.

This Button will be pressed when user's name is being executed.
For Example:

1. Linda pressed the button when item == Linda. And directly the button will show/print Linda's name on spinner1.
2. The same thing happens with other users. and the name will be directtly saved in following spinner (Spinner2).

here is my code...

**MainProgram**

**This main program system's used for looping the names.**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Menu Item selected " + item);
    if (item == Linda) {
        variabel.setViewMode(ClassOne.Object1);
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
        try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        onOptionsItemSelected(David);}
        catch (Exception ex){}}
        }).start();

    } else if (item == David) {
            variabel.setViewMode(ClassOne.Object2);
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
            try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            onOptionsItemSelected(Samuel);}
            catch (Exception ex){}}
            }).start();

    } else if (item == Samuel) {
            variabel.setViewMode(ClassOne.Object3);
          new Thread(new Runnable(){
          public void run() {
          try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          onOptionsItemSelected(Linda);}
          catch (Exception ex){}}
          }).start();
      }
```

**SpinnerProgram**

here is my code...

```
private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

// get the selected dropdown list value
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

public void onClick(View v) {
/* get names when button stop on looping process and print the names in spinners*/
            String name1 = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());
            String name2 = String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem());
            String print_name = getName(name1);
            String print_name = getName(name2);

public String getName(String name) {
        String value = "0";
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Linda")) {
            value = "0";
        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("David")) {
            value = "1";
        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Samuel")) {
            value = "2"; }
```

**STRING.XML**

```
 <string-array name="names">
    <item>Linda</item>
    <item>David</item>
    <item>Samuel</item>
```

**My Question:**

**How to create a button and where should i put the button that can directly print/show the chosen name in spinner?**

Comment: hi mike, thank you for your respond to my question.
No mike, spinner1 is supposed to get only one name from the "OK" button when is pressed.
(The spinner will automatically get the name when button OK is pressed)

I want to put the button "OK" inside method "onOptionsItemSelected" so it can get the name and show the name on spinner.

Comment: After Spinner1's got the name. When we press the OK button for the second time, it will show the name on spinner2.

Comment: it's ok if we have two names on spinners:
Linda on Spinner1
Linda on Spinner2

Comment: i've updated the spinner program. My main points are:

1. How to create button "OK"? (when pressed it will get the chosen name by user)

2. How to connect button "OK" with Spinner? (the button also will select the names on spinner that suited with name that user's choose.

Comment: For example, when user wants to choose David. He will pressed the button OK as fast as (item=David). and directly the name "David" will  be shown on spinner.

Comment: I'm using spinner because i just want to use spinner. my sistem will suite well with spinner

Comment: Did it get you, mike? i'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: When app is starting. The process view on screen will show the names "Linda", "David", "Samuel" (Switching continuously). When user wants to choose one of the names. Ex. David. He will wait till the screen shows "David" then directly he will press the button "OK".

Comment: At the same time the button OK will tell the spinner that user choose "David" so the spinner will automatically show "David". Usually when user wants to choose something in spinner, he will just click the spinner and he will choose the value inside of it. But in my case, i want to make "button confirmation" that will  tell the spinner that the "name" has been choosed, so the spinner will search automatically the name(David) that has been chosen by it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but maybe it will at least help me figure it out by your comments.

**main.xml** layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:entries="@array/names" />

<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:entries="@array/names" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Choose" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
 {
private Button button;
private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;

private long startTime = 0;
private int elapsed = 0;
private final int TIMEOUT = 3;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    handler.postDelayed(run, 0);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    handler.removeCallbacks(run);
    spinner2.setSelection(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition());
}

final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable run = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        elapsed = TIMEOUT - seconds;

        if (elapsed == 0)
        {
            incrementSpinner();
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 0);               
        }
        else
        {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);             
        }
    }
};  

private void incrementSpinner()
{
    int selPos = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();

    if(selPos == spinner1.getCount() - 1)
    {
        selPos = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        selPos++;
    }

    spinner1.setSelection(selPos);
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mike,
I appreciate that. :)